# rnorm is generating non-random looking realizations

Tags: r

I was debugging my simulation and I find that when I run `rnorm()`, my random normal values don't look random to me at all. `ccc` is the mean sd vector that is given parametrically. How can I get really random normal realizations? Since my original simulation is quite long, I don't want to go into Gibbs sampling... Should you know why I get non-random looking realizations of normal random variables?

```
> ccc  
# [1] 144.66667  52.52671  

> rnorm(20, ccc)  
# [1] 144.72325  52.31605 144.44628  53.07380 144.64438  53.87741 144.91300  54.06928 144.76440  
# [10]  52.09181 144.61817  52.17339 145.01374  53.38597 145.51335  52.37353 143.02516  52.49332  
# [19] 144.27616  54.22477

> rnorm(20, ccc)  
# [1] 143.88539  52.42435 145.24666  50.94785 146.10255  51.59644 144.04244  51.78682 144.70936  
# [10]  53.51048 143.63903  51.25484 143.83508  52.94973 145.53776  51.93892 144.14925  52.35716  
# [19] 144.08803  53.34002
```

Comment: Try `rnorm(20, ccc[1], ccc[2])`, and you can use `hist()` to check whether it's distributed as normal.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a basic concept to set parameters in a function. Take `rnorm()` for example:

Its structure is `rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)`. Obviously, `mean` and `sd` are two different parameters, so you need to put respective values to them. Here is a confusing situation where you may get stuck:

```
arg <- c(5, 10)
rnorm(1000, arg)
```

This actually means **`rnorm(n = 1000, mean = c(5, 10), sd = 1)`**. The standard deviation is set to 1 because the position of `arg` represents the parameter `mean` and you don't set `sd` additionally. Therefore, `rnorm()` will take the default value 1 to `sd`. However, what does `mean = c(5, 10)` mean? Let's check:

```
x <- rnorm(1000, arg)
hist(x, breaks = 50, prob = TRUE)
# lines(density(x), col = 2, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

`mean = c(5, 10)` and `sd = 1` will recycle to length 1000, i.e.

```r
rnorm(n = 1000, mean = c(5, 10, 5, 10, ...), sd = c(1, 1, 1, 1, ...))
```

and hence the final sample `x` is actually a blend of 500 `N(5, 1)` samples and 500 `N(10, 1)` samples which are **drawn alternately**, i.e.

```r
c(rnorm(1, 5, 1), rnorm(1, 10, 1), rnorm(1, 5, 1), rnorm(1, 10, 1), ...)
```

As for your question, it should be:

```
arg <- c(5, 10)
rnorm(1000, arg[1], arg[2])
```

and this means **`rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 5, sd = 10)`**. Check it again, and you will get a normal distribution with `mean = 5` and `sd = 10`.

```
x <- rnorm(1000, arg[1], arg[2])
hist(x, breaks = 50, prob = T)
# curve(dnorm(x, arg[1], arg[2]), col = 2, lwd = 2, add = T)
```

[image]